# Overlapping + non-overlapping polygons from two sf objects, sampled at different time points in R

Tags: r, geolocation, r-sf

I have two sf objects (simple feature collections, from gpkg-files), containing sampled a property at roughly the same (but not exactly) locations at two diffent time points. What I need is one object with polygons that provide info about the locations for the two timepoints. See example below.

[image]

For the new object the property should be devided over two attributes: the property at t1 and at t2. This can also be be NA in case this property was not measured at one of the timepoints because of the non-perfect overlap.

I understood that `st_intersection` from package R-package `sf` should be able to do this when your input is one object. With two objects however, this does not work as I expect.

`st_sym_difference()` seems to combine my objects in the right way, but if I input this into `st_intersection()`, I get an error (`Error: GEOS exception`).

EDIT: i want information about all green areas in the figure below, which are overlapping AND non-overlapping areas.

something like this:

[image]

What would be a working approach?

This is what I tried:

```
options(stringsasfactors = FALSE)

library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

t1 <- st_read('T1.gpkg')
t1_int <-  st_intersection(t1)   ## to get rid of overlap within the object

t2 <- st_read('T2.gpkg')
t2_int <-  st_intersection(t2)  ## to get rid of overlap within the object


ggplot()+ 
  geom_sf(data = t1, aes(fill = cat))+ 
  geom_sf(data = t2, aes(fill = cat)) 

t_int <- st_intersection(t1_int,t2_int)      ## keeps only the overlap
t_diff <- st_sym_difference(t1_int,t2_int)   ## keeps all the info in one object with overlaps

ggplot()+ 
  geom_sf(data = t1, aes(fill = cat))+ 
  geom_sf(data = t2, aes(fill = cat))+
  geom_sf(data = t_diff, color = "red", fill = "black",alpha = .4)+
  geom_sf(data = t_int, color = "blue", fill = "blue",alpha = .4)

t_diff %>% st_intersection()                 ## results in error
### Error: GEOS exception
```

Comment: To make sure: you want to determine properties (attributes) *only* for the overlaps of t1 and t2, right?

Comment: no, the overlaps AND the non-overlapping regions!

Answer (score 1):

We don't have your data, so let's make two sf objects with overlapping rectangles representing time 1 and time 2:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

obj1 <- st_polygon(list(matrix(c(0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), 5))) |> 
  st_sfc(crs = 'WGS84') |>
  st_as_sf(time = 1, value = 10) |>
  `st_geometry<-`('geometry')

obj2 <- st_polygon(list(matrix(c(0.1, 2.1, 2.1, 0.1, 0.1,
                                 -0.1, -0.1, 0.9, 0.9, -0.1), 5))) |> 
  st_sfc(crs = 'WGS84') |>
  st_as_sf(time = 2, value = 15) |>
  `st_geometry<-`('geometry')

obj <- bind_rows(obj1, obj2)
```

We now have an `sf` object, with two rectangles at overlapping locations at two different times with two different values:

```r
obj
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: -0.1 xmax: 2.1 ymax: 1
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>   time value                       geometry
#> 1    1    10 POLYGON ((0 0, 2 0, 2 1, 0 ...
#> 2    2    15 POLYGON ((0.1 -0.1, 2.1 -0....
```

And we can plot it to demonstrate:

```r
ggplot(obj, aes(fill = value)) + 
  geom_sf(alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_gradient('value', low = 'deepskyblue', high = 'gold', 
                      limits = c(8, 17)) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

What we need to do now is find the intersection of the two rectangles and store this as a new rectangle with values for time 1 and time 2. We also want to have the symmetrical difference between the two (areas where there was no overlap), and set its values to `NA`. We can use `st_intersection` and `st_sym_difference` for this task, binding the two outputs together:

```r
combo <- bind_rows(st_intersection(obj[1,], obj[2,]),
          st_sym_difference(obj[1,], obj[2,])) %>%
  mutate(across(contains('value'), ~c(.x[1], NA)))
```

Our new sf object looks like this:

```r
combo  
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 4 fields
#> Geometry type: GEOMETRY
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: -0.1 xmax: 2.1 ymax: 1
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>   time value time.1 value.1                       geometry
#> 1    1    10      2      15 POLYGON ((0.1 0, 2 0, 2 0.9...
#> 2    1    NA      2      NA MULTIPOLYGON (((0.1 0.9, 2 ...
```

We can plot it to show the value at time 1:

```r
ggplot(combo) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient('value', low = 'deepskyblue', high = 'gold', 
                      limits = c(8, 17)) +
  theme_void() +
  ggtitle('Value at time 1')
```

[image]

And to show the value at time 2:

```r
ggplot(combo) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = value.1)) +
  scale_fill_gradient('value', low = 'deepskyblue', high = 'gold', 
                      limits = c(8, 17)) +
  theme_void() +
  ggtitle('Value at time 2')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I wasn't clear enough, sorry for that (see edit in my initial post). What I need from your example is three polygons (the overlap, the polygon with only t1, and the polygon with only t2). How can I do that?

Comment: @MartijnM in that case, you don't want the symmetrical difference, but rather both the non-symmetrical differences. In my approach above this would be equivalent to `combo <- bind_rows(st_intersection(obj[1,], obj[2,]), st_difference(obj[1,], obj[2,]), st_difference(obj[2,], obj[1,]))`